# Set 'system:time_start' in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, fields-attributes, image, time

I have an image collection(`image`) with `'system:time_start'`.

My `function(iterate)` is to get `[img1, img1+img2, img1+img2+img3, img1+img2+img3+img4, img1+img2+img3+img4+img5]`.

But after I calculated, I found that the collection (`b`) did not contain `system:time_start`.

The result I expect is，For example,

- `img1+img2 'system:time_start'` is `img2`,
- `img1+img2+img3 'system:time_start'` is `img3`.

Here is the code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/21be41cc79b8b855dbd4fd1cdf03f8c8

Comment: You have to clarify this question - it's not clear what you want to do. The images in your collection b do contain a time_start property.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for your answer. I want to build an Image collection   `[img1, img1+img2, img1+img2+img3, img1+img2+img3+img4, img1+img2+img3+img4+img5]` But after I calculated, I found that the collection (`b`) did not contain `system:time_start`.  I will call this property later.  Kubra helped me sort out the problem, now I explained it clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ee.Image.copyProperties()` function.

```
imageTotals.copyProperties(data, data.propertyNames())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ff5be354c3996948635b25b9b029611d